# How i can remove transparent ball from model?

Tags: edit-mode

How i can remove that transparent ball?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jffb2.jpg
there no way to select her and delete like rest objects.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 1):

look's like you have your clipping value to low.
[image]

the clipping can be found in the n panel or in the camera tab for the camera.
[image]